# How to replace the image src tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="reader1" class="reader monelem_box">
    <div class="monelem_sheaf" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="image">
            <img class="image" alt="image" src="images/img_001.jpg">
```

My javascript code to replace is

```
$("#reader1").attr("src", function () {
    return $(this).attr('src').replace("images", "sunset");
});
```

How can I replace this `src` attribute?

Comment: <idv id="reader1" ... > has to attributes called src...so u have a wrong selector there.. it should be $(".image").attr("src", function () {....

Comment: @user1696555 please accept some answers to your previous questions by clicking the green tick next to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your selector, given your example I'd use:

```
$('img.image', '#reader1').prop('src', function() {
  return $(this).prop('src').replace('images', 'sunset');
});
```

This will limit it to `<img>'s` which have the class `image`, and are descendants of `#reader1`

Answer (score 3):

You are selecting the `div`, you need to select the `img` element. Try this:

```
$("img.image").attr("src", function () {
    return $(this).attr('src').replace("images", "sunset");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this. Instead of `#reader1` use `img.image` there

```
$("img.image").attr("src", function () {
   return $(this).attr('src').replace("images", "sunset");
});
```

or

```
$("img.image").attr("src", function () {
   return this.src.replace("images", "sunset");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#reader1 img.image').attr('src', function (i, a) {
    return a.replace('images', 'sunset');
});
```